# How to update a document using update query in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is the comment key pair I have in my post model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const postSchema = new Schema({
user:{
    type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
 //   required:true,
    refPath:'onModel'
},
onModel:{
    type:String,
    enum:['Doctor','Patient']
},
text:{
    type:String,
    required:true
},
comments:[{
    user:{
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        refPath:'onModel'

    },
    reply:{
        type:String
    },
    date:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
}],
likes:[{
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Patient'
    }
}]
})

module.exports= post = mongoose.model('post', postSchema);
```

When I try pushing object to the likes array by running the following code, it fails. The filter part works fine, just some problem with the update part which ends up executing catch block.

```
Post.updateOne({ _id: req.params.postid, "likes": { $ne : { user: 
authorizedData.jwt_payload.patient._id }}},
    { "$set" : { "likes.$.user": "authorizedData.jwt_payload.patient._id" 
}})
    .then(re => res.json(re))
    .catch(err => res.json("already liked"))
```

Will really appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting upon using `$push`, Is your schema like that ? or can you give us a bit more on schema ?

Comment: When I put a catch block the error i get is: Cannot create field 'user' in element {likes: []}. I dont know if it is something related to cast. I have edited the schema above too please have  alook

Comment: Also I have tried using { $push: { "likes.$.user": authorizedData.jwt_payload.patient._id }}. Also  { $push: { "likes.user": authorizedData.jwt_payload.patient._id }} and lastly  { $push: { likes: {user:  authorizedData.jwt_payload.patient._id }}}. But nothing seems to work

Comment: Ok seems like your schema needs a minor change, can you give us a sample  doc where you've likes array, that way it would be easy to suggest on schema changes..

Comment: I am sorry didn't get you. As in what sample? The last key pair of the schema is the array of objects where I am storing the users who would like the post. Each user would be in an object in that array

Comment: Is that `likes:[{
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Patient'
    }
}]` or `likes:[{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Patient'
}]`

Comment: It is the first one:likes:[{ user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Patient' } }]. Because I need to store the current logged in user's id in user object which would then be in the likes array.

Comment: with that `{ $push: { likes: {user: authorizedData.jwt_payload.patient._id }}}` should work if passed in value is an ObjectId(), what did you see, an error ?

Comment: Ok, you need to convert it before actual DB calls, using `var patientObjectID = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(authorizedData.jwt_payload.patient._id);` and then `{ $push: { likes: {user: patientObjectID}}}`

Comment: Yes it works now using the syntax you said: { $push: { likes: {user: authorizedData.jwt_payload.patient._id }}} . Thank you so much. But still can you explain why couldn't we use the syntax:  { $push : { "likes.$.user": authorizedData.jwt_payload.patient._id
}}. Just curious as where can we use this syntax then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make changes as below :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const patientObjectID = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(authorizedData.jwt_payload.patient._id);
Post.updateOne({
    _id: req.params.postid,
    'likes.user': {
        $ne:
            patientObjectID
    }
},
{ $push: { likes: { user: patientObjectID } } 
}).then(re => res.json(re)).catch(err => res.json("already liked"))
```

Couple of changes need to be done, So When you've a schema like this ::

```
likes: [{
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Patient'
    }
}]
```

1. You need to pass an ObjectId() to user field but not a string, So
   first we're converting string to ObjectId() & passing it in query.
2. Also `$set` is used to
   update existing or insert new fields in a document, but when you wanted to push
   new values to an array field in a document then you need to use
   `$push`(this seems to be a normal update operation on a field, but here we're not replacing the likes array, rather we're just adding few more elements to it - different kind of update though, So that's why we need to use `$push`).
3. As you already have below filter, we're just doing `$push` assuming what we're pushing is not a duplicate but in the other way you can blindly use [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/index.html) to do the same without having to use below filter criteria :

   ```
   "likes": {
       $ne: {
           user:
               patientObjectID
       }
   }
   ```
4. About your question on [$(update)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/index.html) why it isn't working ? This should be used to update the elements in an array, it helps to update first matching element in an array based on filter criteria, but what you wanted to do here is to add few more elements but not updating existing elements in `likes` array.
5. Here you should not send "already liked" in catch block, it should be a custom error for an actual error, in `.then(re => res.json(re))` you need to check write result of update operation if anything updated you need to send added user, if not you need to send "already liked".

Hope this solves all your questions :-)

Comment: Yes it does. You really cleared some messed up concepts. Thanks :)

Comment: @Emma : Hey I've updated this answer with few other findings, you can embed those in your code..

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$push` aggregation which is used for pushing objects to inner arrays in mongoDB. Your update query should be something like the following:

```
Post.updateOne({ _id: req.params.postid, "likes": { $ne : { user: 
authorizedData.jwt_payload.patient._id }}},
    { "$push" : { "likes": authorizedData.jwt_payload.patient._id
}})
    .then(re => res.json(re))
    .catch(err => res.json("already liked"))
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. When I try updating a field that is string, it updates successfully but here it fails.